# Launch screen for PhoneGap iPad Google App Engine Latitude API app

Tags: iphone, google-app-engine, oauth, cordova, google-latitude

I have a Google Appengine app that uses the Latitude API, and OAuth. In my web-based version of the app, the first thing that happens is that the user authenticates, via OAuth. I want to make this run on PhoneGap, so I can deploy my app to the iPad. (The reason I can't just use it as a brower app is the it's going to use phono.js, which has built integration libraries for PhoneGap).

My question concerns the launch screen. I tried creating an index.html file by copying the html source I see when I go to : http:// my_phono_app.appspot.com , when the user is not logged in.

But when I do this, and fire it up in the simulator, using xcode, it tries to jump to a url beginning with: accounts.youtube.com/accounts/CheckConnection..., but just hangs there.

So I'm guessing that it tries to go to my_phono.appspot.com, sees that it needs to authenticate, but then gets lost in the weeds, from my perspective.

So is there a way I can accomplish what I want here, which is for the user to authenticate to Google, and then be on their merry way to my app?

Comment: Did you figure out how to authenticate on Appengine from the PhoneGap app?